# parse information from expect command

Tags: linux, ssh, tcl, expect

I need to parse resulting data from a `telnet/ssh` command and act on the data.

**As an example**, I want to interact with a spawn session (`ssh` here), list files in current dir and collect only file of a certain extension to later execute a command on those files only.

What I've got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 3
match_max 10000
set prompt {$ }

spawn ssh $user@$host
expect "password: "
send $pw\r
expect $prompt

# here's the command I need to parse resulting data
send "ls -1\r"
expect -re {(.*)\.log} {
    set val $expect_out(1,string)
    puts "LOG file: $val"
    exp_continue
}
```

That script opens a `ssh` session, sends the command and displays **all** the files in current dir (log and others) but I need to process each file matching a given pattern, how can I do this?

**script output:**

```
$  DATA: 
0_system.log
1_system.log
2_system.log
3_system.log
a.log
a.sh
blah
b.sh
data.csv
```

Comment: Don't think you need both the braces and the quotes round your regex

Comment: Did that actually solve the problem? I last did Expect about 8 years ago :-)

Comment: I think your regex should be in braces - see my official answer and discussion below. I'd be grateful if you could tell us whether either quotes or braces work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all... wouldn't `ls -1 *.log` be easier, and do the trick?

That said, I have found that usually you have to be very careful when using `(.*)`, it can have at times unexpected results.

I would go with "any alphanumeric character plus underscore" (if that works for your filenames) - see my suggested expect block below. Also, keep in mind that by using `$expect_out(1,string)` you are saving **only the filename, without the extension** - not sure if that is what you want. If you want the whole thing, `$expect_out(0,string)` is the way to go in this case.

This will do it:

```
expect -re "(\[a-zA-Z0-9_\]*)\.log" {
    set val $expect_out(1,string)
    puts "LOG file: $val"
    exp_continue
}
```

Hope that helps!
James

Comment: `ls -1 *.log` doesn't work in my case, as I'm just showing the type of output I'm getting from the device. It's actually a proprietary command and not `ls` in the real scenario.

Comment: getting the regex right is key in this situation. Updating my script now works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Corrected Expect probably should be:

```
expect {
    -re {(.*)\.log} {
        set val $expect_out(1,string)
        puts "LOG file: $val"
        exp_continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: More likely `{(.*)\.log}` as backslashes are Tcl quoting characters in double quotes, and so `\.` ends up interpreted as `.`, which isn't what's wanted here.

Comment: You're probably right, like I said I last did Tcl and Expect about 8 years ago, however I looked in Don Libes book and \n and \r are definitely accepted in double quotes, so I'm not entirely certain what happens to \. I've amended my example anyway.

Comment: using `{(.*)\.log}` as regex is right. But I still get the whole list of files in $val, as if the regex isn't working

Comment: The regex may be greedy. The (.*) may be capturing everything up to the last log.